# I want to use the Document.querySelector() method to log specific text wrapped in <a> tags

Tags: javascript, console

I want to log all the text that is wrapped in   tags and that has the .link and the .linkNewLine class. I want to log those in the console so i can copy them into an excel sheet with each link text in a separate line. As I will have an excel sheet with about 200 links it would be nice to do this via the the console and not by copy pasting each value separately. Probably Document.querySelector() is the right method here but how would I write my Query?

```
<tr>
<td>
<a class="link linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">The Text I want to grab</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="link linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">Another line of text I want to grab and put in a new row in excel</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">This line should not end up in my excel</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Show us a sample portion of your HTML that you want to get the text from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is `querySelectorAll`

(`querySelector` only returns a single node)

```js
(function(n){var a=[];
  for(var i=0;i<n.length;++i){
    console.log(n.item(i).textContent);
    a.push(n.item(i).textContent);
  }
 document.body.innerHTML=('<pre>'+a.join('\n')+'</pre>')
}(document.querySelectorAll('a.link.linkNewLine')))
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<a class="link linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">The Text I want to grab</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="link linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">Another line of text I want to grab and put in a new row in excel</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="linkNewLine" target="_blank" href="/link/foo/bar">This line should not end up in my excel</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works great the only problem is that I get  a code like this VM4714:4 after every line in chrome and it pastes that into my excel table.

Comment: This string comes from the console, you may use another way to avoid it(e.g. print the desired text directly inside the document). See the modified code snippet

Comment: One aditional question how would I change document.querySelectorAll('a.link.linkNewLine') to pick all a tags within td tags?

Comment: the argument passed to querySelector/querySelectorAll expects a CSS-selector, the rules are the same as you would use in CSS: `td a.link.linkNewLine`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to log those text in console. Here is a code snippet

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('link') && $(this).hasClass('linkNewLine')){
        console.log($(this).text()+'\n');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the page does not use jquery and I can't include it because it is not my page...

Comment: I am not sure if my answer will be helpful or not,....you can add jQuery through browser console like this
"
var head = document.head;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js';
head.appendChild(script);"

this will add the library and then you can execute the above snippet in browser console to get your result.